How to export configs from azure app configuration to app service in a different subscription?
I have been scouring documentation and issue logs for days now. I need to figure out how to successfully export my configs as reference to my app services that live in subscriptions that are different than were the app configuration service resides.
I can successfully login to azure cli with my service principal which has access to both my prod subscription (App Configuration Service location) and my test subscription (App Service location)
az login  --service-principal --username XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX --password XXXXXXXXXXXXX --tenant XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX
I then set my account to my test subscription (where my app service is located) and verify it is set correct with az account show
az account set -s TEST-SUBSCRIPTION-NAME
az account show
Next to test that I can access the App Configuration Service in my production subscription even though I am logged into my test subscription I run the az appconfig kv export with the export going to file
az appconfig kv export --destination file --connection-string 'Endpoint=https://prod-app-config-service.azconfig.io;Id=XYZK;Secret=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ' --label my-label --skip-features true --format yaml --path config.yml
This command successfully generates the config.yml file.
However, when I try to export to my app service directly without exporting to file, I get errors:
az appconfig kv export --destination appservice --connection-string 'Endpoint=https://prod-app-config-service.azconfig.io;Id=XYZK;Secret=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ' --label my-label --export-as-reference true --skip-features true --appservice-account test-app-service
Failed to find the App Configuration store 'prod-app-config-service'
If I try to use the full ARM ID of my app service, then I get the following error:
az appconfig kv export --destination appservice --connection-string 'Endpoint=https://prod-app-config-service.azconfig.io;Id=XYZK;Secret=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ' --label my-label --export-as-reference true --skip-features true --appservice-account /subscriptions/test-subscription-id/resourceGroups/rg-test-app-service/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/test-app-service
Failed to read key-values from appservice. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
Update 1: Screen Shot From GitHub Action.  See comment:
enter image description here
Update 2: It seems that I can recreate the error:
Failed to read key-values from appservice. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
By adding the environment variable:  DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD. If I remove that variable then the export from the App Configuration Service to my App Services works.  If I add that variable, even with a simple "Testing" value, the I get the "Failed To read key-values" error.

You need to login into the azure account again with az login CLI command and set the other subscription in which the app service existed.

When you are passing the ARM ID of the app service account, the ID should be in the below format as shown.
Refer MSDoc for the relevant information.
/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<Appservice>/config/web
az appconfig kv export:
az appconfig kv export --name myconfigj --destination appservice --appservice-account /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/appsjah/config/web --label test --export-as-reference true --connection-string 'Endpoint=https://myconfigj.azconfig.io;Id=NIlX;Secret=heEnla4lhTE1V8EckgSxxxxxxxxJ99AFACYeBjFAArohAAACAZACioul'


Once it is exported, execute the below command to retrieve the app settings configuration.
az webapp config appsettings list --name appsjah --resource-group xxxx


Portal view:
App service >> Settings >> Environment variables >> app settings



Really appreciate your quick response and I was so hopeful that it was going to work, but no luck. Ultimately, I am trying to do this in a GitHub Action. So I created a dummy app service web app and created a dummy label in my App Config Service.  As you see in the screen shot, it will not export to my app service in a different subscription. I ran "Get Current Environment Variables" to show that the "Login Via Azure CLI" is authenticated to access the dummy app service, and the "Export App Config To File" proves that I can reach the App Config Service.

What is the error it is showing now? @BrettB

see my Update 2.
